# Emacs query-replace-regexp with html

Tags: regex, emacs, replace

I was trying the *replace-regexp* command in *Emacs* but I've no idea about how to construct the right regexp. My file looks like the following:

```
<img src="http://s.perros.com/content/perros_com/imagenes/thumbs/1lundehund2.jpg" />
<img src="http://s.perros.com/content/perros_com/imagenes/thumbs/1pleon2.jpg" />
```

And I want to replace for:

```
<img src="" class="class-1lundehund2.jpg" />
<img src="" class="class-1pleon2.jpg" />
```

I was using this regexp with no success (*Replaced 0 occurrences*):

```
M-x replace-regexp
  Replace regexp:  src\=\"http\:\/\/s\.perros\.com\/content\/perros_com\/imagenes\/thumbs\/\([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\)\"
  Replace regexp with: src\=\"\" class\=\"class-\1\"
```

But in *re-builder* mode with the same regexp (changing **\([a-zA-Z0-9.*-]+\)*** by **\\([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\)**) all the results are right highlighted. I've no idea of what's happening, any tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're escaping too many things.  regexp = `src="http://s\.perros\.com/content/perros_com/imagenes/thumbs/\([^"]*\)"`, replacement = `src="" class="class-\1"`

Comment: Thanks! it runs so well. You must be right, I was escaping lot of things, thanks again.